# Formulario de Contacto con reCaptcha

Tags: php, html, captcha

Tengo un formulario de Contacto y quiero implementar reCaptcha pero la verdad que no he podido, he intentado pero no logro que mi código PHP valide que la Captcha no esta resuelta y no permita enviar el formulario. A continuación mi código PHP y HTML usado.

En el `<head></head>` he puesto como dice la pagina oficial:

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

HTML:

```
    <form action="enviar.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h1 class="title">Contáctanos</h1>
    <input name="name" required="required" placeholder="Nombre">
    <br>
    <input name="email" type="email" required="required" placeholder="Email">
    <br>
    <select name="enquirytype">
        <option value="1">Publicar un Libro</option>
        <option value="2">Error con Algún libro</option>
        <option value="3">Otro error</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <textarea name="message" cols="20″ rows="5″ required="required" placeholder="Mensaje"></textarea>
    <br>
   <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="MiClaveAquí"></div>
    <br>
    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

PHP (enviar.php):

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = 'From: YourWebsite.com'; 
    $to = 'micorreo@gmail.com'; 
    $subject = 'Soporte Técnico - RelaxMind';
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $select_enquirytype = strip_tags($_POST['enquirytype']);

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message \n Option $select_enquirytype \n IP User: $ip";
?>

<?php
if ($_POST['submit']) {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
        echo '<p>Gracias, nos comunicaremos lo mas pronto posible!</p>';
    } else { 
        echo '<p>Oh no! Hubo un error, Intenta mas tarde :(</p>'; 
    }
}
?>
```

Decir que he usado tal cual como en la Ayuda de reCaptcha aparece, solo que no logro que PHP me valide que fue o no fue resuelto el Captcha. Ese sería todo mi código, me podrían echar una mano? Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La parte cliente (el html) es correcta, pero **falta la parte del servidor** donde se comprueba si se ha pasado el recaptcha.

En el *enviar.php* deberías de añadir algo tal que así:

```
$captcha =  isset( $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] ) ? $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] : '';
if (!$captcha) {
   die('Por favor resuelva el captcha');
}

$secret = 'tu_clave_secreta_de_recaptcha';
$response = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secret."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']), true);

if ($response['success'] === true) {
   // Aqui envías el correo del formulario etc
} else {
   die('Captcha incorrecto, actualice la página pulsando F5');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$response = null;
// comprueba la clave secreta
$reCaptcha = new ReCaptcha($secret);
if ($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]) {
 $response = $reCaptcha->verifyResponse(
$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
$_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]
);
}
if ($response != null && $response->success) {

// Si el código es correcto, seguimos procesando el formulario como siempre
}else{
//Mensaje para avisar que debe completar el captcha
}
```

Esto va en tu código de enviar.php.