# Formulario de contacto seguro

Tags: php, html

¿De qué forma puedo implementar el siguiente formulario para evitar el injection y Spam?
Agregué reCaptcha pero al parecer no es suficiente.
Es molesto estar recibiendo correos Spam casi a cada rato.
¿Alguien tiene alguna idea?

```
<?php
$remitente = $_POST['email'];
$destinatario = 'ejemplo@mail.mx';
$asunto = 'Buzon';
if (!$_POST){
?>

<?php
}else{

$cuerpo = "Nombre Completo: " . $_POST["nombre"] . "\r\n"; 
$cuerpo .= "Email: " . $_POST["email"] . "\r\n";
$cuerpo .= "Telefono Particular: " . $_POST["telparticular"] . "\r\n";
$cuerpo .= "Telefono Celular: " . $_POST["telcelular"] . "\r\n";
$cuerpo .= "Mensaje: " . $_POST["mensaje"] . "\r\n";

$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n";
$headers .= "X-Priority: 3\n";
$headers .= "X-MSMail-Priority: Normal\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: php\n";
$headers .= "From: \"".$_POST['nombre']." ".$_POST['apellido']."\" 
<".$remitente.">\n";

mail($destinatario, $asunto, $cuerpo, $headers);

include 'index.html';
}
?>
```

Espero de su ayuda, salvarían mi vida sin duda alguna.

Comment: Supongo que pusiste el recaptcha en el frontend pero tienes que validar el campo con la api de PHP, y no se ve eso en tu código. Checa la documentación de recaptcha para PHP

Comment: Puedes probar a utilizar zend_mail, pear mail, swift mailer, suhosin... Aquí puedes obtener [más información en inglés](https://www.damonkohler.com/2008/12/email-injection.html) de como funciona el Mail Injection y el spam anonimo. También al final te dice posibles soluciones

Comment: Perdón José, pero no tiene nada que ver qué función utiliza para enviar su correo, con el spam que le llega a través del formulario, que es lo que no está validando por utilizar el recaptcha solo en el frontend y no en el ćodigo que PHP que valida el token que debería venir en el parámetro de recaptcha.

Comment: Acá tienes una referencia en español de lo que te falta que es validar el token recibido por recaptcha: http://jonsegador.com/2017/05/configurar-recaptcha-2-0-con-php/

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Formulario de Contacto con reCaptcha](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/74539/formulario-de-contacto-con-recaptcha)